# there is a scroll end event for recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a recycler view and I want to capture the event when the user finishes scrolling; which I assume is when the user lifts his finger from the screen, I have tried the nItemTouchListener [onTouchEvent] event but I have not been successful, in fact the event does not fire, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reached it using OnScrollListener:

```kotlin
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                //do something when scroll
            } else {
                //do something when stop scroll
            }
        }
    })
```

Here is how I use it in my project, I've just created the extension function to hide and show Fab button:

```kotlin
fun RecyclerView.addFabListener(fab: FloatingActionButton) {
    this.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                fab.hide()
            } else {
                fab.show()
            }
        }
    })
}
```